# gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: maven, gpg

Размещал библиотеку в maven central, и, соответственно, подписывал её как надо, и проделывал все нужные шаги.
Последний раз обновлённую версию я выкладывал очень давно (несколько месяцев назад), в основном были мелкие обновления (и то редко), которые шли лишь на гитхаб.
Сейчас появилась необходимость пересобрать один старый проект, который использует эту библиотеку, — подключать её как локальную зависимость я не хочу, ибо это не так удобно (используется мавен).
Раньше я пользовался одной особенностью — если я делаю изменения у себя на компьютере, использую один из мавен-тасков (`install`, если мне не изменяет память), то изменения идут в локальный репозиторий, и после этого, без удалённого добавления в мавен репозиторий, можно в `pom.xml` добавить даже новую версию проекта, которая есть только локально, и всё будет работать.

Это была предыстория, теперь вопрос: я несколько месяцев назад менял ноутбук, а все основные действия происходили на нём, в том числе генерация ключей `gpg` и вот это всё. Сейчас появляется ошибка при попытке `mvn install`:

`gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Как я понимаю, ошибка появляется потому что мой ключ не совпадает с тем, который был ранее (я его сгенерировал только что).

Есть ли какие-либо способы решения этой проблемы?
К старому ноуту доступа нет, да и перед продажей всё было очищено и os переустановлена, так что доступа к данным старым я бы всё равно не получил, а про это совсем забыл.

Или, может, ошибка в чём-то другом?
Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Решается проблема (по крайней мере, для локального репозитория), довольно просто:

Добавить в **~/.gnupg/gpg.conf**:

```
use-agent  
pinentry-mode loopback
```

Добавить в **~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf**:

`allow-loopback-pinentry`

Затем перезапуск: `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent`

Справедливо для linux и osx.

[Источник](https://d.sb/2016/11/gpg-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-errors).